# input field becomes blank when tabbing out

Tags: sapui5

This [simple form](https://github.com/colmsjo/openui5-sbx/tree/master/src/eventsapp.validationbug) clears out the input field when a number >1000 is entered. I've tried to add formatOptions but it does not make any difference.

This is the relevant part of the code.

```
<Input
      description="Quantity"
      placeholder="Float"
      width="100%"
      type="Number"
      value="{path:'/classified',
      type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Float',
      constraints: {minimum: 1, maximum: 1001},
      formatOptions: {pattern: '#,##0.###'} }">
  <layoutData>
      <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S2"/>
  </layoutData>
</Input>
```

For clarity 1001, which is allowed by the validation, is also cleared out.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/susute/1/edit?html,output) is a jsbin showing this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenUI5/SapUI5 team has given me the solution. `type="Number"` should not be used. It works fine if this is removed.